# WordPress multisite suddenly malfunctioning

Tags: multisite

I've suddenly got multiple points of failure on a WordPress multisite:

- Nothing within the_post() is displaying on any site, apart from images
- There's no access to the backend at all, beyond the log-in screen there's a blank screen
- Child theme stylesheets are only being partially applied

I haven't updated or added any plug-ins on WordPress for a couple of weeks: last thing I did was changed one site's child theme stylesheet, and left the whole thing working as normal.

Does anyone know what might be the cause, and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: A blank screen just indicates an error occurred and that you need to look at the PHP error log to see what it was. Without knowing what those error messages are the problem you're asking about is a mystery that cannot be diagnosed remotely. Please follow the standard WP debugging routines with `WP_DEBUG`, disabling plugins/themes to identify the culprit, and checking error logs

Answer (score 0):

Repeating @Tom's answer so this question will not be unanswered:

> A blank screen just indicates an error occurred and that you need to
>   look at the PHP error log to see what it was. Without knowing what
>   those error messages are the problem you're asking about is a mystery
>   that cannot be diagnosed remotely. Please follow the standard WP
>   debugging routines with WP_DEBUG, disabling plugins/themes to identify
>   the culprit, and checking error logs.